# issue with setting condition when combining the tabs together

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to combine my tabs into one combine sheet but i do not want to combine with one of the sheet. The sheet name is called table 1. Currently it is able to combine all but i dont wish to combine one of the tab. It would be helpful if you could help me. Thank you

```
Option Explicit

Sub Combine()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim combinedWs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim copyRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Add combined worksheet and populate headers
    Set combinedWs = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1))
    combinedWs.Name = "Combined"
    Sheets(2).Rows(1).Copy combinedWs.Rows(1)

    ' Loop through rest of Sheets
    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set ws = Sheets(i)
        With ws
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "N"))
            copyRng.Copy combinedWs.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            If ws = ("Table 1") Then Exit For



        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you know about the sheet that you don't want to add to the combined sheet? Do you know the name or index number?

Comment: @Beek the name of the sheet that i do not wish to add is called Table 1

Comment: But what goes wrong using your code? I would firstly change `combinedWs.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` with `combinedWs.Cells(combinedWs.Rows.Count, 1)`, if you want to copy according to the last empty row of "Combined" sheet. Otherwise, your code wrongly calculates the range rows... And also `Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1)...` to be transformed in `Set copyRng = ws.Range(.Cells(2, 1)`. They must refer the appropriate sheet.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am trying to loop through my entire sheet and combine it but exclude a sheet name called Table 1

Comment: @Beek: So, do you need only that sheet exclusion and your code runs as expected, except of that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `If` statement to your loop. like so:

```
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name <> "table 1" Then
            Set ws = Sheets(i)
            With ws
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Set copyRng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "N"))
                copyRng.Copy combinedWs.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            End With
        End If
    Next i
```

And remove the `If ws = ("Table 1") Then Exit For` line.
This way you don't exit the `for loop` when you come to the table 1 sheet, but you move to the next sheet without copying anything.